# Why does a <ul>/<ol> treat a block of text like you're a <p> around it?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a couple of `<ul>/<ol>`, and for some reason it is treating the `<ul>/<ol>` like a `<p>`.  What can I do to work around this error?

codepen: http://codepen.io/q695/pen/PPzwWq

```
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
</p>
Lorem i:
<ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum</li>
<li>Dolor sit</li>
<li>Consectetuer<</li>
</ul>
<p>
Epsum factorial non deposit quid pro quo hic escorol. Olypian quarrels et gorilla congolium sic ad nauseum. Souvlaki ignitus carborundum e pluribus unum. Defacto lingo est igpay atinlay. Marquee selectus non provisio incongruous feline nolo contendre. Gratuitous octopus niacin, sodium glutimate. Quote meon an estimate et non interruptus stadium. Sic tempus fugit esperanto hiccup estrogen. Glorious baklava ex librus hup hey ad infinitum. Non sequitur condominium facile et geranium incognito. Epsum factorial non deposit quid pro quo hic escorol. Marquee selectus non provisio incongruous feline nolo contendre Olypian quarrels et gorilla congolium sic ad nauseum. Souvlaki ignitus carborundum e pluribus unum.
</p>
```

Comment: What you asking is not clear. Is the `left-margin` (left space) of ul/ol you talking.?

Comment: `li` are block level elements as `p` or `div`. Reference -https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

Comment: I want to make a <ul>/<ol> heading appear right on top of the bullet points, not include a gap in it.

Comment: @webfarm.io Check out the answer i posted, it might help you.

Comment: nope, but it could help someone else with a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the `ul`'s margin, add this CSS:

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n6y45b97/)